# how to tell rsync to preserve time stamp on files when source tree has a mounted point

Tags: backup, rsync

> Related to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61497/rsync-command-to-backup-home-tree-to-another-disk)

**Short description of the problem:**

When source tree has a mounted point inside it, then time stamps on files inside that mounted point when copied to target tree are not preserved even when using `-a` option

**Detailed description:**

Assume this is the source tree:

```
                       /home/                           /home/
                         |                                |
                        me/                             BACKUP/
                         |                                |
                    +----+----------+                +----+-------+
                    |    |          |                |    |       |
                 data/  foo.txt    boo.txt         data/ foo.txt boo.txt
                    |                                |
                   a.txt                           a.txt
```

where `data/` above is mounted external USB disk. Everything is `ext4` file system. Everything in source is owned my `me`.

`BACKUP` also happened to be a mount point, the backup USB disk.

After issuing this command `rsync -av --delete  /home/me/  /home/BACKUP/`, I found that `/home/BACKUP/data/` and everything below it has the current time stamp, as if these files were created now, and not the time stamp on the files in `/home/me/data/`.  Other files and folders outside `data` did have the time stamp preserved OK.

Question is: How to use `rsync` in the above setting to tell it to preserve time stamps on all files and folders even on files and folders on a mounted point?

I am using:

```
>uname -a
Linux 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

>rsync -v
rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

from `man rsync`:

> ```
>    -t, --times                 preserve modification times
> ```

Since you are copying files from one filesystem to another and wanting to preserve `c-time`.  Most people understand `c-time` to mean "create time" which is incorrect on most UNIX/Linux systems (Windows filesystems track "creation" or "birth" times).

For the most part, in UNIX and Linux, `c-time` is the timestamp used to record the last inode '**C**'hange.  An inode changes if any of its attributes are updated:

- creation (OP's case)
- mode (permissions)
- owner/group
- hard link count
- [etc. (stat() system call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call))

OP cannot preserve the `c-time` of their file's when they are brought onto a new filesystem.  The creation of these files in the new filesystems is one of the conditions listed above (creation of inode/file).

Comment: Thank you. I know that. But please read the question again carefully. I did use `-a` which says: `archive mode; equals -rlptgoD ` therefor `-t` is already included.

Comment: are you trying to preserve change time?  ctime is NOT for "created" its for (status) change

Comment: I want it to work just like it does on files that are not on the mounted disk. i.e. keep the same time stamp that one sees when doing `ls -l` on the file. This works on files that are not inside the mount point. But all files that are inside the mount point, have time stamp on them indicating they were just created. Whatever you call this time. I just wanted it to use the same time stamp on the files in the source. Now it does not. I want all time aspects be copied. i.e. a clone of the file be made. creation time, change time, etc...

Comment: the change time (ctime) gets updated upon a change to the inode (ie. creation/permission change/moving/etc).  because you are creating a new inode (because you are copying the file accross a filesystem (separate inode tables) the ctime is updated.  there is no way around that because it is the change of the inode, not the file. take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)#ctime

Comment: `ls -l` shows mtime (modify) not ctime

Comment: `rsync -a` or `rsync -t` preserves the time which is shown by `ls -lc` not `ls -l`.

Comment: @ora-600 It is actually the contrary: `ls -lc` displays ctime (inode change time) whereas `rsync -a` or `rsync -t` preserve mtime (modification time).

Answer (score 17):

as hr3miller already said, -a (or --archive) is equal to -rlptgoD and already includes syncing time.

However when rsync copies data to, eg. an NFS/FAT32/NTFS mount where preserving user and owner fails, rsync won't try to set the time. Rsync will warn with something like

```
rsync: chown "/mnt/backup/postgres/hourly.0/primary/var" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

Therefore leave out preserving user and group by using

```
-rlptD
```

instead of

```
-rlptgoD
```

Only use this when not preserving the owner and group is an option for you.
Note that preserving symlinks and other features could trigger that behavior, too. You will have to go through the man page for every rsync feature (-r -l -p -t -g -o -D) you want to backup.

Comment: From man pages: `-r` is "recurse into directories", `-l` is "copy symlinks as symlinks", `-p` is "preserve permissions", `-t` is "preserve modification times", `-g` is "preserve group", `-o` is "preserve owner (super-user only)", `-D` is "same as --devices --specials", `--devices` is "preserve device files (super-user only)", `--specials` is "preserve special files".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `touch` tool for that. The `-r` argument will copy the timestamps from one file / folder to another.

```
cd srcParentDir
find srcDir -exec touch -r {} /target/dir/{} \;
```

Or for your example:

```
cd /home/me
find . -exec touch -r {} /home/BACKUP/{} \;
```

which will execute the following statements:

```
touch -r ./data/a.txt /home/BACKUP/./data/a.txt
touch -r ./foo.txt /home/BACKUP/./foo.txt
touch -r ./boo.txt /home/BACKUP/./boo.txt
```

And thus basically copy the old timestamps to the new filesystem.

If you have spaces in the destination path you have to escape them `/home/my\ spaced\ path/`. I think `{}` will do the escaping for you, though I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score -2):

I use `rsync -az` and sure thing it preserves me the modification time. I double-checked it right now.

Comment: That's because `-a` (`--archive`) includes `-t`.

Comment: However no, ctime cannot be arbitrarily reset. (I misunderstood the quesiton originally, sorry.)